# How to increase volume on a virtual machine?

Tags: macos, mac, virtual-machine, osx-el-capitan

I've installed OS El Capitan using VMWare Workstation and sound is too low, for example, testing iTunes. Is there a way to make it loud in the same level as happens in Windows (which is, in my case, the host of VMWare)? I've read that virtual machines use some "buffer" to make sound work, but I didn't find a config where I could make changes to increase sounds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific volume command for a virtual machine. You control the volume in the Guest OS by adjusting the volume as you would do on a normal phyisical machine.

Setting this to 100% will make it as loud as the VM is allowed to go, which is always at maximum is going to be the volume you use for your OS.

If you use windows as host, and you open the volume mixer, you can alter the volume for each individual program. If the volume here is set to low, your VM will have that as maximum volume.

Also, the `audio buffer` has nothing to do with volume. Its about caching sounds.

Comment: this answer isn't right, becuase it indicates that virtualbox is not the source of this problem. not so. virtualbox clearly has a legitimate issue here: all else being equal, virtualbox vms are significantly lower in volume compared to any other application. under a windows 10 host, the only workaround is to compensate by using the sound mixer to turn down all other applications. unfortunately, this means when you start any new application, you will be deafened by its default volume until you compensate it for virtualbox. virtualbox's deficiency here requries all other apps to be modified

Comment: @ChaseMoskal I use VirtualBox on a daily basis and don't recognize this issue, but that said, OP uses VMWare, so that invalidates your comment.